# ActiveRecord::Base::serialize automatically unserializes for some fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, serialization

I am serializing two nearly-identical fields on a single model, and when I call the accessor method for one of them, I get the deserialized object, but when I call the accessor method for the other one, I get the `ActiveRecord::AttributeMethods::Serialization::Attribute` struct.

The difference I see is that for the first field, I declare `serialize` in an `included` block of a mixin Module; for the second field, I declare `serialize` in the class declaration (as normal).

What's causing this? How can I bring the behavior of these two fields into uniformity?

*Rails 3.2.13*

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I moved the problematic `serialize` declaration (the one which did not produce an automatically-deserializing accessor method) upward a couple of lines so that it appeared *above* my `attr_encrypted` declarations.